# could not start eureka server in spring boot due to tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, build.gradle, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I was trying to learn microservices and created eureka server class to start eureka server. I declared
spring-cloud-netflix-eureka dependency in gradle build from maven central repository.after runnig the applicaton it throws apache.catalane.lifecycleException. failed to start component. And I dont know where tomcat comes into picture when Im trying to work on eureka.

this is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server:3.1.4'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

this is my main class

```
package org.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(EServerApplication.class,args);
    }
```

this my application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
```

this is the error

```
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
```

I have tried changing the version of dependency, have tried adding spring web dependency,changed gradle version but nothing seems to work out.

Comment: Please add the full error

Comment: Hey Spencergibb, sorry I had not added the actual error only. Don't know how I forgot it, but I have added it now, help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is the the full error? No stack trace?